# Twitter bootstrap form styles not functioning as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In the following jsfiddle I've got an inline form with an input and a submit. When I reduce the screen size the input jumps to be 100% width - which is obviously the responsiveness kicking in. Problem is the submit button doesn't get a 100% width applied....which is something I'd expect if bootstrap has applied 100% to the input.

Any ideas why this is?

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" style="width: 350px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div class="form-group" >
     <label for="postcode" class="sr-only">Postcode:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="email" placeholder="Postcode">
   </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orettyqv/

Comment: Why do you expect that the button would have a 100% width applied to it?

Comment: I knew that was coming. Because bootstrap applies 100% width to the input - to cater for smaller screen size...is it not a fair assumption to expect it to apply the same to the submit? Otherwise you end up with the situation I have in the fiddle...

Comment: The only reason your `input` is 100% width is due to the `form-control` class you have applied to it. You could apply that to your `button` too but it also fixes the height which you likely don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't make `button` elements 100% wide by default at any breakpoint, you have to do it on your own, in this case with a media query. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .btn {
        width: 100%; 
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/orettyqv/1/